# The props of a component rendered inside a route will never update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-component

What I am trying to do is getting the login user's information from the login component, so that the App component could pass the login user's information to the main component.

Here is some code in the App.js:

```
state = {
   usersArr: [],     // all the users
   logInUser: 0,    // the login user, default value as 0
}
getLogInUser = () => {
    return this.state.logInUser;
}
assignLogInUser = user =>{
    this.setState({logInUser: user});
    console.log("LogIn: " + this.state.logInUser.username);

}
render(){
return(
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/main" exact render={() => <Main logInUser={() => this.getLogInUser()}/>}/>
                    <Route path="" exact render={() => <Landing usersArr={this.state.usersArr} getUser = {this.assignLogInUser}/>}></Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
)
}
```

The first page would be landing page and the landing component would be rendered. The landing component will render the login component. The login component will check if the username and password from input would match any user in the usersArr. If it does match, the login component will call the assignLogInUser to assign the login user.

landing.jsx:

```
render(){
   return(
       <Login usersArr={this.props.usersArr} getUser={this.props.getUser}/>
   )
}
```

login.jsx:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.userName = React.createRef();    // username referrence
        this.password = React.createRef();    // password referrence
    }
validateLogin = () => {
    this.props.usersArr.forEach(user => {
        if(user.username === this.userName.current.value && user.password === this.password.current.value){
                this.props.getUser(user);
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is that the logInUser passed into the main is always 0.

Looks like once the route has been set up, it will never update the component it's going to render. No matter what I tried, I would get the default value 0 for logInUser in the main component.

I can probably use redux, but I have to refactor all of the code.

I have tried forceUpdate() in the main component, or using key in the main component. None of them works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `the username and password machtches` seems to be a crucial part, what does it actually say there? Also, you have both `logInUsers` and `logInUser`, and you seem to use it to store the index at one point, then to store the user object at another.

Comment: @ChrisG It just checks if the input matches any user's username and password. I have updated the code in the login.jsx with constructor and validateLogin method. Yup, good catch, "logInUsers" was a typo.

Comment: Found it: Replace `<Main logInUser={() => this.getLogInUser()}/>` with `<Main logInUser={this.getLogInUser()}/>` or just `<Main logInUser={this.state.logInUser}/>` (you wanted to pass a value but passed a function getting the value instead)

Comment: @ChrisG The problem is that the logInUser props of Main in the route never update. So, it will call the getLogInUser at the compile time and the value of logInValue will never change. I actually gave up using this approach, I used localstorage to store the login user information, which is now working!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I built a test app using your code, and the fix I suggested *fixed* the issue. `Main`'s prop updated according to which user logged in, as expected. Again, the issue was that you were setting `Main`'s prop to a *function* as opposed to a value. function props are what you use for event handlers and the like, but you passed a function as *value prop*. With your code, `this.getLogInUser()` never did get called. See for yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cloud-vv3ob

Comment: @ChrisG Wow, thank you so much for the test app. It actually works!!! I guess you are right. I thought the arrow function is going to get called when the App trying to render the component.